# Use SUBSTITUTE formula to remove text from string in Excel, with text to remove being referenced from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following sheet setup

```
Column A - Brand Names
Column B - Product Names
```

The product names are structured as:

```
Nike Air Force White
Addidas Trainers Black
```

I want to remove the brand name from the start of each product name. Therefore I think I need to create a formula to use the brand name from Column A and delete that from Column B.

I'm using Excel 2014 Mac

Comment: Is the brand always first in the string?

Comment: One important thing: how about brand names with two or more words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cell references in the [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function, like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,C1,"")
```

`A1` is `"Nike Air Force..."`

`C1` is `"Nike"`

Result is `" Air Force..."`

Wrap the function in [`TRIM`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) to get rid of the leading space.

Comment: JDB - Thanks for the fast support. Worked great.